# Size of sitemap.xml

Tags: asp.net, web, sitemap

What should be maximum size of Sitemap.xml for any e-commerece ASP .Net website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps#cite_note-sitemaps.org-2):

> The file must be UTF-8 encoded, and
>   cannot be more than 10MB large or
>   contain more than 50,000 URLs, but can
>   be compressed as a gzip file.

Comment: Note that the 10Mb is the maximum size UNCOMPRESSED. http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index

Answer (score 0):

Well actually if you are developing e-commerce website, it would be best practice to write your own SiteMapProvider and store the links in database. So you don't need to worry about any xml-based deficiencies.

Comment: I do have all the urls in database. I am generating sitemap.xml file in our root directly for search engine such as Google, Live Search, Yahoo.